# Generating an IEEE bibliography with book series in parentheses using BibTeX and IEEEtran

Tags: bibtex, formatting, ieeetran

The IEEE citation reference and style manual both list the following two bibliography examples for books:

> [4]  M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun, Eds., *Handbook of Mathematical
>   Functions* (Applied Mathematics Series 55). Washington, DC: NBS, 1964,
>   pp. 32-33.
>
> [5]  E. F. Moore, “Gedanken-experiments on sequential machines,” in
>   *Automata Studies* (Ann. of Mathematical Studies, no. 1), C. E. Shannon and J. McCarthy, Eds. Princeton, NJ: Princeton Univ. Press,
>   1965, pp. 129-153.

I'm trying to create a reference to a portion of a book (similar to [5] above) and cannot figure out how to get the series portion to show up in parentheses as in the above examples.  Here is what I am using:

```
@incollection{dsp_handbook,
    title = {Subspace-based direction-finding methods},
    author = {G{\"o}nen, E. and Mendel, J.},
    address = {Boca Raton, {FL}},
    edition = {2nd},
    series = {Electrical Engineering Handbook},
    booktitle = {The Digital Signal Processing Handbook: Wireless, Networking, Radar, Sensor Array Processing, and Nonlinear Signal Processing},
    publisher = {{CRC} Press},
    editor = {Madisetti, Vijay},
    year = {2009}
}
```

and this is what I get:

> [13] E. Gönen and J. Mendel, “Subspace-based direction-finding
>   methods,” in *The Digital Signal Processing Handbook: Wireless,
>   Networking, Radar, Sensor Array Processing, and Nonlinear Signal
>   Processing*, 2nd ed., ser. Electrical Engineering Handbook, V.
>   Madisetti, Ed. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press, 2009.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?